# How come in Safari my image won't float to the left of my paragraph

Tags: css

My website loads fine in Chrome, but in Safari my image won't float to the left of my article. Here is a look at the CSS:

```
body    {
    background-color:white;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
}

.top_portion    {
    width:820px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:5px;
    border-bottom:5px;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#30474b;
}

.top_portion    img     {
    padding-top:0px;
}

#welcome    h1  {
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

#welcome    h3  {
    margin:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

#welcome    {
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
    width:820px;
}

#navigation {
    text-align:center;
}

#navigation li  {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;;
}

ul  {
    font-size:20px;
    margin:0;
}

ul a {
    padding-right:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

a:hover {
    color:#888eee;
    }
```

This is the div containing the image and the article

```
.info {
    width:820px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is the image

```
.info img { 
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

And here is the article this is and the .info img above should be next to each other but they aren't in Safari which has been updated to the latest version.

```
article {
    padding-left:5px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-indent:15px;
    width:600px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:justify;
}

article h2  {
    font-family: 'Carme', sans-serif;
    margin-top:5px;
}

h5  {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

a   {
    color:black;
}

#bottomlink {
    font-size:1.5em;
    text-align:center;
}

#bottomlink a   {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: you should display a link... or a least a jsfiddle with the problem... one cannot simply read all that css and imagine an answer

Comment: gotcha ill work on that right now

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/saQataQ/LZjd9/ Okay here is the jsfiddle but it lines up properly there it just seems in safari the image and the <p> aren't adjacent

Comment: Thank you it worked! Someone messaged me to put float:left; for the image and don't bother with float:right on the article and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

float:left; for the img
and don't bother float:right; on the article